# How to Fix : TypeError: page.locator(...).toContainText is not a function

Tags: automation, assertion, playwright-test

Tried Msplaywright for Automation: I was trying to check if the meta description of my site is correct by adding an assertion = .toContainText

Unfortunately, I got this error:
"toContainText is not a function"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPa7N.png)

Any idea on how to fix this? Here is my full code:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';   


test('Landing page', async ({ page }) => { 
    await page.goto('https://www.unient.biz/'); 
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept All' }).click(); 
    const MetaDescription = page.locator(("//meta[@name='description']"));
    await expect(MetaDescription ).toContainText('Empower your organisation to function onshore and offshore as one enterprise by using our versatile range of services and regional service delivery')
        
        });
```

Comment: On the line where you define the locator, is the `\` actually the end of the line? As that is likely causing the issue if so. Also, looks like you have an extra set of parentheses there too, but that doesn’t affect behavior at all, just redundant.

Comment: Its actually the end of line, here is the full code. I updated above for the full code:

Comment: Weirdly, it looks like my `\\` didn’t show up in my originally comment  If you remove that slash, does it work as expected? I expect that would cause issues.

Comment: I removed the / at the en of the line  (I just noticed it just as you mentioned) but still the same , I got the same error

Comment: It looks like you reposted, but with a different error now, so it looks like you’re actually not getting the same error anymore. Can you please confirm? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75651129/playwright-expect-tocontaintext-not-working

Answer (score 1):

This code will run perfectly:

```
test.only('Page Playwright Test', async ({ page }) => {
    const ExpectedText = "Empower your business to function onshore and offshore as one enterprise with Unient's versatile range of services and regional service delivery capabilities.";

    await page.goto('https://www.unient.biz/');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept All' }).click();
    const MetaDescription = page.locator("(//meta[@name='description'])[2]");
    const ActualText = await MetaDescription.getAttribute('content');
    expect(ExpectedText).toEqual(ActualText);
});
```

The issue with the original code was that there were two elements with the same XPath, //meta[@name='description']. This refactored code addresses that problem.