# Playwright. expect ToContainText not working

Tags: automation, playwright, assertion, playwright-test

I created a script to validate the meta description in our sample website. I added toContainText assertion, but it's not working and on my end:

This is the error:

```
    import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
        
    test('Landing page', async ({ page }) => {
      await page.goto('https://www.unient.biz/teams');
      await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Accept All' }).click();
      const MetaDescription = page.locator(("//meta[@name='description']"));
      await expect(MetaDescription).toContainText("Scale faster and smarter and gain access to a premium global talent pool with our fully customisable offshore team solutions: Employer of Record and Managed Resources.");
    });
```

Error here :
[uploaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hern.png)  - Or you can check below:

```
Error: expect(received).toHaveText(expected)

Expected string: "Scale faster and smarter and gain access to a premium global talent pool with our fully customisable offshore team solutions: Employer of Record and Managed Resources."
Received string: ""
Call log:
  - expect.toHaveText with timeout 5000ms
  - waiting for locator('xpath=//meta[@name=\'description\']')
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  - waiting for locator('xpath=//meta[@name=\'description\']')
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""
  -   locator resolved to <meta name="description" content="Scale faster and sma…/>
  -   unexpected value ""


   7 |   const MetaDescription = page.locator(("//meta[@name='description']"));
   8 |   //MetaDescription.getAttribute("//meta[@name='description']");
>  9 |   await expect(MetaDescription).toHaveText("Scale faster and smarter and gain access to a premium global talent pool with our fully customisable offshore team solutions: Employer of Record and Managed Resources.");
     |                                 ^
  10 |
  11 |
  12 | });
```

Comment: what are you trying to store in MetaDescription? your locator's innerText() is returning empty string. You can use MetaDescription.getAttribute("content") which will return the expected string to do assertion

Comment: Sorry @itronic1990, I edited the code it was not properly formatted: it should be this one:
const MetaDescription = page.locator(("//meta[@name='description']"));

Comment: I think itronic is pointing to the fact meta elements aren’t visible ones to the user, and don’t actually containText. Did you have visible text you were trying to assert against? Otherwise if you’re trying to assert on the content attribute, you’ll need to assert on that. Although instead of getting the attribute and then asserting as he suggested, you can just expect the locator [toHaveAttribute](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-attribute). Unless a substring is needed, that is.

Comment: @SarahG Could you also provide a snippet of the HTML code that contains what you are trying to select?

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to the element with the name description. But you don't want the reference to it, you don't want the element itself, you need the text inside it:

```
const MetaDescription = page.locator(("//meta
[@name='description']")).getText();
// or
const MetaDescription = page.locator(("//meta
[@name='description']")).InnerHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tag looks like this

```html
<meta name="description" content="Scale faster and smarter and gain access to a premium global talent pool with our fully customisable offshore team solutions: Employer of Record and Managed Resources." style="" xpath="1">
```

So you have to validate the attribute value, not elements text.

```js
await expect(MetaDescription).toHaveAttribute(
    "content",
    "Scale faster and smarter and gain access to a premium global talent pool with our fully customisable offshore team solutions: Employer of Record and Managed Resources.",
);
```

or full code

```js
import { test, expect } from "@playwright/test";

test("Landing page", async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.unient.biz/teams");
  await page.getByRole("button", { name: "Accept All" }).click();
  const MetaDescription = page.locator("meta[name='description']");
  await expect(MetaDescription).toHaveAttribute(
    "content",
    "Scale faster and smarter and gain access to a premium global talent pool with our fully customisable offshore team solutions: Employer of Record and Managed Resources.",
  );
});
```

see https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#list-of-assertions